# splitting at underscore in python and storing the first value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like df with a column construct_name

```
construct_name
aaaa_t1_2    
cccc_t4_10
bbbb_g3_3
```

and so on. I want to first split all the names at the underscore and store the first element (aaaa,cccc, etc.) as another column name.

**Expected output**

```
construct_name  name
aaaa_t1_2       aaaa
cccc_t4_10      bbbb
```

and so on.

I tried the following
`df['construct_name'].map(lambda row:row.split("_"))` and it gives me a list like

```
[aaaa,t1,2]
[cccc,t4,10]
```

and so on

But when I do

`df['construct_name'].map(lambda row:row.split("_"))[0]` to get the first element of the list I get an error. Can you suggest a fix. Thanks

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Just use the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) and use integer indexing on the list to get the first element:

```
In [228]:

df['first'] = df['construct_name'].str.split('_').str[0]
df
Out[228]:
  construct_name first
0      aaaa_t1_2  aaaa
1     cccc_t4_10  cccc
2      bbbb_g3_3  bbbb
```

Comment: `.str[0]` was important . I was wondering what's wrong with `df['construct_name'].str.split('_')[0]`

Answer (score 11):

Another way of using the vectorised `str.split` method is passing the `expand=True` flag which then returns one column for each of the split parts.

```py
>>> s = pd.Series( ['aaaa_t1_2', 'cccc_t4_10', 'bbbb_g3_3'], name='construct_name')

>>> s.str.split('_', expand=True)  # to see what expand=True does
      0   1   2
0  aaaa  t1   2
1  cccc  t4  10
2  bbbb  g3   3

>>>  s.str.split('_', expand=True)[0]  # what you want, select first elements
0    aaaa
1    cccc
2    bbbb
```

This would be specially useful if you wanted to keep the first and second values for example.

In terms of the general behaviour of the `expand=True` flag, note that if the input strings do not have the same number of underscores you ca get `None`s:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series( ['aaaa_t1_2', 'cccc_t4', 'bbbb_g33'], name='construct_name')

>>> s.str.split('_', expand=True)
      0    1     2
0  aaaa   t1     2
1  cccc   t4  None
2  bbbb  g33  None
```

Answer (score 8):

```
df['name'] = df['construct_name'].str.split('_').str.get(0)
```

or

```
df['name'] = df['construct_name'].str.split('_').apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 4):

After you do the `split`, you should get the first element (using [0]). And not after the `map`.:

```
In [608]: temp['name'] = temp['construct_name'].map(lambda v: v.split('_')[0])

In [609]: temp
Out[609]: 
  construct_name  name
0      aaaa_t1_2  aaaa
1     cccc_t4_10  cccc
2      bbbb_g3_3  bbbb
```

Answer (score 3):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) take an optional argument `maxsplit`:

```
>>> construct_name = 'aaaa_t1_2'
>>> name, rest = construct_name.split('_', 1)
>>> name
'aaaa'
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a method for pandas not on a single string