# How to drop each values after symbol "/" in column in Pandas Data Frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1
--------
abc
aaa/bcd
ghi/jke/zpo
rtv
```

And I would like to delete each values after "/". So as a result I need something like below:

```
col1
--------
abc
aaa
ghi
rtv
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [splitting at underscore in python and storing the first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947574/splitting-at-underscore-in-python-and-storing-the-first-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```py
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.split("/").str[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  col1
0  abc
1  aaa
2  ghi
3  rtv
```

Comment: What is string split ? and why there is [0] ?

Comment: @Matop for example `.str.split("/")` will split the `ghi/jke/zpo` to `['ghi', 'jke', 'zpo']` so we want only first element - we use `[0]`

Comment: Ok, great, for 6 minutes I will give you best answer! thank you

Answer (score 0):

With [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and the `expand` option, you just have to take the first column in the resulting dataframe:

```
>>> df['col1'].str.split('/', expand=True)[0]
0    abc
1    aaa
2    ghi
3    rtv
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on the answers given by Andrej and Cimbali, you can also use the `lambda` function inside `map()` as below. Split each element of the column by "/" and get the first element:

```
df["col1"].map(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
```