# Removing words to the right of a string in a dataframe

Tags: python, string, text, replace, nlp

I have a data frame that contains a description of services performed on a vehicle. I would like to remove the word VIN followed by all words to the right of it.

```
Description
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 CX-5 Vin.#J1452239 St.#G3056 Per.Wally/Joseph Blenkinsop
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 Terrain Vin.#JL225216 St.#218369 Per.Toby
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 Terrain Vin.#JL286535 St.# Per.Tanner
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 Yukon Vin.#JR297209 St.# Per.Randy/victoria Celaya
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 19 1500 Vin.#KG174232 St.# Per.Colby
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 19 1500 Vin.#KG265533 St.# Per.Colby
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 19 Blazer Vin.#KS644905 St.# Per. J.C.
```

I have not gotten any useful output using prefix/suffix. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [splitting at underscore in python and storing the first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947574/splitting-at-underscore-in-python-and-storing-the-first-value)

Comment: Hi! Did you end up solving your problem?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["Description"] = df["Description"].str.replace(r'\s*\bVin\b.*$', '', regex=True, flags=re.I)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `pandas`

Since your strings are in a DataFrame, you can use pandas methods directly rather than calling python standard library functions on individual strings.

Most method from python's `str` are available in pandas, directly applicable to a Series or DataFrame.

- [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'description': '''Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 CX-5 Vin.#J1452239 St.#G3056 Per.Wally/Joseph Blenkinsop
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 Terrain Vin.#JL225216 St.#218369 Per.Toby
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 Terrain Vin.#JL286535 St.# Per.Tanner
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 Yukon Vin.#JR297209 St.# Per.Randy/victoria Celaya
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 19 1500 Vin.#KG174232 St.# Per.Colby
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 19 1500 Vin.#KG265533 St.# Per.Colby
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 19 Blazer Vin.#KS644905 St.# Per. J.C.'''.split('\n')})

df['short description'] = df['description'].str.split('Vin', 1).str[0]

print(df['description'][0])
# Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 CX-5 Vin.#J1452239 St.#G3056 Per.Wally/Joseph Blenkinsop

print(df['short description'][0])
# Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 CX-5
```

### Using python's builtin `str`

Without using any regexps, you can use `str.split` to split the string on `'Vin'`, then keep only the left half:

```py
s = 'Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 CX-5 Vin.#J1452239 St.#G3056 Per.Wally/Joseph Blenkinsop'

left, right = s.split('Vin', maxsplit=1)

print(left)
```

Output:

```
Install Ceramic Film on the front 2 roll up on a 18 CX-5
```

Or alternatively:

```py
left = s.split('Vin', maxsplit=1)[0]
```

If you wanted to split on the last occurrence of `'Vin'` instead of the first occurrence, then you could use `rsplit` instead of `split`.

Relevant documentation:

- [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split);
- [str.rsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).